# asp.net core call controller using jquery-ajax-unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I had Html.beginForm for creating and downloading an excel(called a function from the controller) and it was working fine.

I want to add a loader spinner for the time it takes to create and download the file.
As i understand, i cant use Html.BeginForm to catch onComplete (or some event after download is complete) and stop the loader.
so, i changed it to jquery-ajax-unobtrusive,
Now the controller is being called and onComplete function is also called
but the file is not downloading.
cant understand why

My controller function:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Export(ExcelUploadsForShopsVM excelUploadsForShopsVM)
        {
            ExcelUploadsForShops ex = _unitOfWork.excelUploadsForShops.GetAll().Where(a => a.StoreId == excelUploadsForShopsVM.excelUploadsForShops.StoreId && !a.TrackingUpdated)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            string storeName = _unitOfWork.UserStoreName.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == ex.StoreId).Select(a => a.StoreName).FirstOrDefault();
            string fileName = storeName + "_" + DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + "_HH" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_MI" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ".csv";
            IEnumerable<Order> orderList = _unitOfWork.Order.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id >= ex.FromOrderId && a.Id <= ex.ToOrderId).
                                           OrderBy(a => a.Id);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            //Header
            int lineCounter = 0;
            using (var dbContextTransaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                  .
                  .
                  long code that creates the file
                }
                catch
                {
                    ViewBag.errSaveInProgress = true;
                }
            }
            return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
        }
```

calling the controller from the view:

```
<div class="col-6 text-left">
    <form asp-action="Export" asp-controller="OrderAdmin" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-complete="OnComplete">
                <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="excelUploadsForShops.StoreId">Store</label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.excelUploadsForShops.StoreId, Model.StoresListTR , "Select Store",
                       new { @class = "form-control" })
                        <span asp-validation-for="excelUploadsForShops.StoreId" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:forestgreen">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>&nbsp;Download Tracking
                </button><img src="~/gif/WMDx.gif" alt="Loader" style="height:40px; width: 40px; display:none;" id="divLoader2">
                </form>
        </div>
```

in _layout i did add the jquery-ajax-unobtrusive under jquery:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

I found out that if i'm removing the data-ajax='true', then the file
is downloading but the data-ajax-complete function is not called.
if data-ajax='true' is added, then data-ajax-complete will be called but file is not downloading :\

Comment: What is the purpose of adding ajax to file download?

Comment: I want to show a spinner for the time the user is waiting for the file to download...
once the function in the controller is done and file is downloading i want to stop the spinner

Comment: try to add `method="post"` alongwith the `data-ajax-method="POST"`. See whether it makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you Deepak-MSFT, but its still the same...

Comment: In my search, I found that Data-ajax has several attributes. I suggest you also try to make a test with the `data-ajax-begin` or `data-ajax-complete`. See whether it helps to fix the file download issue. [Reference link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2015#issuecomment-173005074).